# C++ Safe strings between different DLL's and even threads

Tags: c++, string, multithreading, dll

What string container is the best when talking about passing it between DLL's and different threads, and DLL's may have different runtime libraries, like Multi-threaded Debug.

E.g. const char* ?

Performance is NOT a concern!

Comment: `const char*` is not a container and will be safe across all boundaries (C has a specified ABI).  Others (`std::string`), not so much.

Comment: Not sure if the standard containers are thread safe. You may have to wrap a std::string to be thread safe

Comment: I'm afraid there's no such thing as a thread-safe string in standard C++. What you might want to look for is an *immutable string* class; perhaps there are some good open-source implementations available. An immutable string would be obviously thread-safe.

Comment: strictly speaking, `char*` is not a string container.

Comment: CString from MFC or ATL is fine, guess DLL implies windows and msvc anyway.

Comment: Using `BSTR` and warpper class like `ATL::CComBSTR` should be working fine. As it contain only one member `BSTR m_str` and no virtual methods. ATL `CString` also contain only one member and no virtual methods.

Answer (score 0):

The best container to use if it does not need to be a dynamic string is
    `static const char* exampleText = "Your string goes here";`